# Need Neo4j Data Format json in c#

Tags: c#, graph, neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I'm trying to find the shortest path along with relations on the nodes on the path, for which below query is used.

```
MATCH p = shortestPath((p1:Person { name: 'Kevin Bacon' })-[*..15]- 
  (p2:Person { name: 'Meg Ryan' })) 
  UNWIND nodes(p) as n 
  MATCH (n)-[*]->(q) 
  RETURN n, q
```

However i want to return the result as json object with data format as below in c#. I understand we have to use apoc. However can't really understand how to proceed.

```
{
"results": [
    {    
        "data": [
            {
                "graph": {
                    "nodes": [
                        {
                            "id": "1",
                            "labels": ["James"],
                            "properties": {
                                "ShortName": "jammy",
                                "Type": "Person",
                                "Age": 34
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "2",
                            "labels": ["Brad"],
                            "properties": {
                                "name": "Brad",
                                "PlaceOfBirth": "California",
                                 "Type": "Person",
                                "description": "Nice actor",
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "3",
                            "labels": ["Titanic"],
                            "properties": {
                                "movieName": "Titanic", 
                                 "Type": "Movie",         
                                "description": "Tragedy",
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "relationships": [
                        {
                            "id": "4",
                            "type": "ACTED_IN",
                            "startNode": "1",
                            "endNode": "3",
                            "properties": {
                                "from": 1470002400000
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
],
"errors": []
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can collect the nodes and relationships separately and add it on the result.

```
MATCH p = shortestPath((p1:Person { name: 'Kevin Bacon' })-[*..15]-(p2:Person { name: 'Meg Ryan' })) 
  UNWIND nodes(p) as n 
  MATCH (n)-[r]->(q) 
  WITH collect(distinct n) + collect(distinct q) as node_list, collect(distinct r) as rel_list
  RETURN {results: {data: {graph: {nodes: node_list, relationships: rel_list}}, error: []}} as output
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot. I'm getting used to Neo4J.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted the first level incoming and outgoing relations of all the nodes on the path. Slighty modified the answer for anyone looking for something similar in future. Thanks Jose.

```
MATCH p = shortestpath((p1:Person { name: 'Kevin Bacon' })-[*..30]-   
(p2:Person { name: 'Meg Ryan' })) 
UNWIND nodes(p) as n 
MATCH (n)<-[r*1]->(q) 
WITH collect(distinct n) + collect(distinct q) as node_list, 
collect(distinct r) as rel_list
RETURN {results: {data: {graph: {nodes: node_list, relationships: 
rel_list}}, error: []}} as output
```